# Angular 4.x: How to bind table checkbox with button in Angular 4.x?

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I am  new in Angular 4.x. I have a html table. Every row has a checkbox and a checkbox. I want to bind checkbox with button, so that when the checkbox is checked, the button is enabled, and when the checkbox in unchecked, the button is disabled: 
here is a sample of code, but it is not working :

```html
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" [checked]="item.checked"></td>

      <td>{{i}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      <td>{{item.age}}</td>
      <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="item.checked">start</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Can you help me to make this work please ?

Answer (score 9):

use `[(ngModel)]`. Because `check` will not enable the two-way binding. It just handles One-way changing

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="" [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></td>
```

make the button disable not equal to item check, like this `[disabled]="!item.checked"`

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!item.checked">start</button></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently your checkbox only binds one way. To apply changes by clicking it, add the following to your input tag:
`(change)="item.checked = !item.checked"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need checked directive. Just binding the model is enough.

```html
  <tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;">
  <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></td>

  <td>{{i}}</td>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.email}}</td>
  <td>{{item.age}}</td>
  <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!item.checked">start</button></td>
<pre>{{item.checked}}</pre>
</tr>
  </tbody>
```

```html
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="" [checked]="item.checked"></td>

      <td>{{i}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      <td>{{item.age}}</td>
      <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="item.checked">start</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    <td>
       <div class="togglebutton">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="record.status" (change)="changeStatus(record.id,$event)">
             <span class="toggle"></span>

            </label>
       </div>
    </td>
```